# cscript prnport.vbs Remote Desktop Connection Error 0x80041001 Generic failure

Tags: windows, cmd, server, wsh

I'm trying to run the following command on a remote server (Windows Server 2008r2) but it comes up with 0x80041001 Generic failure - I am running CMD in Admin mode and I know the script works as it will run on my local Windows 8 PC.

Any advice would be great!

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnport.vbs -a -r TEST -h 10.227.190.10 -o raw -n 9100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My account was an Active Directory account. It had to be a local account to work :)